# Проблема с выводом списка файлов JList

Tags: java, файлы

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста. Никак не получается вывести список файлов с помощью JList. Пишу сервер на сокетах. Данные со всех соединений записываются в файлы. Для отображения всех подключений хочу использовать список файлов находящихся в определенной папке. Для отображения файлов использую JList только он выводит не список файлов а 16-ричное значение. Как сделать так, что бы выводился список файлов?

```
public class VisualPanel {
JFrame JF = new JFrame();
JPanel JP = new JPanel();
JScrollPane JSP = new JScrollPane();
JScrollPane JSPArea = new JScrollPane();
JTextArea JTA = new JTextArea();

public void visual() throws FileNotFoundException{
    JF.setSize(1400, 1200);
    JF.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JF.setLayout(null);
    JF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JF.setTitle("Leprikon");
    JF.setVisible(true);
    JP.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JP.setBounds(0, 0, 1300, 700);
    JP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
              BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),
              " ",
                    TitledBorder.RIGHT,
                    TitledBorder.BOTTOM,
                    null,
                    Color.blue));
    JP.setVisible(true);
    JP.setLayout(null);
    JTA.setLineWrap(true);
    JTA.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JTA.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    JTA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JTA.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    JTA.setVisible(true);
    JSP = new JScrollPane();
    JSP.setBounds(510, 5, 500, 500);
    JSP.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    JSP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
              BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),
              " ",
                    TitledBorder.RIGHT,
                    TitledBorder.BOTTOM,
                    null,
                    Color.blue));
    JSP.setVisible(true);
    JSPArea = new JScrollPane();
    JSPArea.setBounds(5, 5, 500, 500);
    JSPArea.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    JSPArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
              BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),
              "ClientsDir",
                    TitledBorder.RIGHT,
                    TitledBorder.BOTTOM,
                    null,
                    Color.blue));
    JSPArea.setVisible(true);
    JSP.getViewport().add(JTA);
    String dirname = "/home/andrey/workspace/SocketFileServer";
    File f1 = new File(dirname);
    String[] line1 = f1.list();
    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    Object[] lineList = f1.list();
    dlm.add(0   , lineList);
    JList list = new JList(dlm);
    list.setBounds(5, 5, 500, 500);
    list.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(0); 
    JSPArea.add(list);
    list.revalidate();
    JSPArea.validate();
    JSPArea.repaint();
    JP.add(JSP);
    JP.add(JSPArea);
    JF.add(JP);
    JF.repaint();

}
```

Comment: В дополнение к ответам: `DefaultListModel` - параметризованный тип, и можно указать, какие объекты должен содержать его экземпляр. Если бы вы объявили модель, как `DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<>();`, ошибка была бы обнаружена в момент компиляции, т.к. `dlm.add(0   , lineList);` принимал бы в качестве аргументов строку, а не массив объектов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод DefaultListModel.add добавляет один элемент, он не умеет обрабатывать списки. А вы в него массив пихаете. Вот список адрес этого массива и показывает.

Чтобы показать список файлов для начала добавьте каждый элемент отдельно. Ну и у каждого объекта File берите нужное строковое значение (getName, getPath), а не кладите его самого.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы подсказать: как правильнее добавить каждый элемент по отдельности? Попробовал сделать так. for(int i = 0; i<lineList.length; i++){
   dlm.add(i, f1.list());
  } теперь выдает разные значения. Но все равно 16-ричные

Comment: @lemuur `String[] files = f1.list(); for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++){ dlm.add(i, files[i].getName()); }`

Comment: Почему-то не получается. line1 не имеет в наличии метода getName.

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо большое) Сделал вот так String[] files = f1.list(); for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++){ dlm.add(i, files[i]); }

Comment: Опечатался, попробуйте снова. А вобще вы что то не очень код понимаете который пишите. Вы б не со свинга начинали с чего нить по проще.

Comment: Да я месяц всего java занимаюсь) Спасибо большое еще раз)